# Do we need [aircraft-purchase]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just notice that we have the tag [aircraft-purchase](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-purchase).

Is this a proper tag? Or should we burninate it?

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: @DanHulme feels a bit like a meta-tag. if it is just me, ok, I apologise

Answer (score 1):

My gut says we don't really need it—or, at least, we need to clarify what it's supposed to mean.

I see that currently, the tag has questions asking

- whether or not it's possible to purchase a particular type of aircraft,
- whether a particular price for a particular aircraft is realistic or not,
- which aircraft to purchase for a particular purpose,
- what the regulations are for exporting aircraft,
- why certain aircraft aren't very popular,
- how aircraft are transported to the buyer,
- what the advantages and disadvantages are of certain kinds of aircraft,

and many other things. It almost seems like no two questions use the tag the same way.

An "aircraft purchase" question could reasonably be about the regulations governing the sale of aircraft, or about the business decision of buying an aircraft for business use, or the personal decision of buying an aircraft for personal use; and all three of these are separate and largely unrelated topics, with not enough in common to have a single tag for all three of them, but not sufficiently many questions to justify an individual tag for any one of them.

In short, these questions don't seem to have anything in common that would warrant all having a common tag.

(If we do keep the tag, can we at least rename it to [aircraft-buying](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-buying)?)